# How can I get headers of the URL from chrome-php

Tags: chromephp

I am using **chrome-php**
I want to get the header from the response
Is there any way I can get it?
Here is how I am trying to implement the functionality ...

```
$browserFactory = new BrowserFactory('chromium-browser');

// starts headless chrome
$browser = $browserFactory->createBrowser([
    'noSandbox' => true,
    'debugLogger' => 'php://stdout',
]);

try {
            
    $page = $browser->createPage();
    $page->navigate($url)->waitForNavigation();

    info([$page->getHtml()]);

finally {
    $browser->close();
}
```

Comment: Where you able to find an answer to this?